# Android: how to use callback on Crouton onDisplayed()

Tags: java, android, callback, android-lifecycle, crouton

I would like to start a new activity, but only AFTER my Crouton has been displayed.

I would like to use the onDisplayed() function of the Crouton
https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/blob/master/library/src/de/keyboardsurfer/android/widget/crouton/LifecycleCallback.java

and then call my activity as follows

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

I've been trying to create my callback function, but with no luck so far...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved as follows.

In my Activity called "TestActivity" I called:

```
showCroutonMsgThenGoToActivity(text);
```

And in the same Class I added these functions:

```
public void showCroutonMsgThenGoToActivity(String text) {
    Crouton toShow = null;

    LifecycleCallback myCallback = new LifecycleCallback() {
        public void onDisplayed() {
            // do nothing
        }

        // Will be called when your {@link Crouton} has been removed.
        public void onRemoved() {
            skipToNextActivity(MyNewActivity.class);
        }
    };


        //create config 
        Configuration myConfig = new Configuration.Builder().
                setDuration(1000)  
                .build();

        //create style
        Style myStyle = new Style.Builder().setConfiguration(myConfig)
                .setBackgroundColor(R.color.green) //check your color!
                .build();

        //apply my custom stile
        toShow = Crouton.makeText(TestActivity.this, text, myStyle);

    toShow.setLifecycleCallback(myCallback);
    toShow.show();
}


private void skipToNextActivity(Class c) {
    // go to next activity
    Intent i = new Intent(this, c);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```